# Access to leads for customer community users

Tags: community, security, leads, customer-community

This is a generic question. Is there any possible way to give visibility to leads to a customer community user.

In the below article

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_visibility.htm

under Records (such as accounts, leads, opportunities)

it is written

Can see records they own, and ones they have access to (based on sharing rules and permissions) across all communities.

As per my understanding I believed, I cannot give access to leads to customer community users.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access Leads with customer community licenses. The section you referred here is only for representation based on what "*they have access to*". Leads are accessible only with Partner Community licenses.

You can find out specifically which objects are supported by which type of community licenses at the help link below. The table in there has all details(snapshot below).

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5

[image]